# Visual Studio 2010 .Net Launch Condition

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, outlook, add-in

.Net Launch Condition version in Visual Studio for my setup is set as .NET Framework 4 Client Profile. But when i compile my .msi and run it on windows 7 x64 it complains that "The Microsoft Office solution cannot be loaded because a compatible version of the .Net Framework is not installed."

The solution is creating an addin for MS Outlook 2010 x64.

I have installed the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile on the machine but it still complaining about it. Any ideas please?

Comment: Why don't you just use the full version?  It is only 15% bigger.  The Client profile is pointless and was removed in 4.5

Comment: Because client version is installed on all workstations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were reference to Full version 4 in Applciation deployment section. Corrected that and it isntalled fine.